# How to authenticate logged in user when refreshing single page application using AngularJS without "Routing"?

Tags: java, angularjs, servlets, single-page-application

I searched a lot of resources but none was appropriate to my problem.I am working on `single page application (SPA)` project ,and I want a `logged in user` to `stay logged in` whenever he refreshes the page **but** **without** **routing**.

I have tried to call `session authentication servlet` in the main `controller` of the page(this servlet checks whether the session exists or not),but it did not work.

Note: The session is created once the user `log in` or `sing up`.
Here is `SessionAuthServlet.java`:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
User u=(User) session.getAttribute("usersession");
try{
    response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    if(u != null)
    {
        out.println("{\"+success+\"}");
        out.close();
    }
    else
    {
        out.println("{ \"result\": \"fail\"}"); 
        out.close();
    }
    }catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

`MainController` in HTML single page application:

```
appvar.controller('MianController',['$scope','$http','$rootScope',function($scope, $http,$rootScope) {                      
    $rootScope.sessionvalid=function(){
        $http.get("http://localhost:8080/MyProject/SessionAuthServlet")
        .success(function(response) {
            if (response.result=="fail")
                {
                  //***Show the view for not logged user      
                }
                  //***Show the view for logged user
                }

                $rootScope.sessionvalid();
       });
    }
}]);
```

Any ideas how to deal with this?

Please guide me

Thanks

Comment: use localstorage or session

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can stay logged after page refresh without using routing. 
You will need below three things

1. A angular service to hold user information and if he is authenticated or not.
2. A window sessionstorage to save user information. Even if the page is refereshed the user information will persist in sessionstorage
3. An interceptor to set request and response.

**Service code -**

```
    app.service('AuthenticationService', function() {
        var auth = {
            isLogged: false,
            email:"",
            isAdmin:false
        } 
        return auth;
    });
```

In your MainController, once user is logged in set the Service AuthenticationService.isLogged = true and $window.sessionStorage = userInfo

**Interceptor code-**

```
    app.service('TokenInterceptor', function ($q, $window, $location, AuthenticationService) {
return {
    request: function (config) {
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        if ($window.sessionStorage.token) {
            config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.sessionStorage.token;
        }
        return config;
    }, 

    /* Set Authentication.isAuthenticated to true if 200 received */
    response: function (response) {
        if (response != null && response.status == 200 && $window.sessionStorage.token && !AuthenticationService.isAuthenticated) {
            AuthenticationService.isAuthenticated = true;
        }
        return response || $q.when(response);
    }
};
});
```

and in your app.config block add this -

```
app.config(function($httpProvider){
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(TokenInterceptor);
})
```

Now your AuthenticationService.isLogged will remain true even if the page is refershed and you can get the logged in user info in the service.